# Probability of selection of three key to unlock the houses.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, conditional-probability

A real estate man has eight master keys to open several new houses. Only one master key will open a given house. If 40% of these houses are usually unlocked,the probability that the real estate man can get into a specific house,if he selects three master keys at random,is?

My approach:
Let the 3 keys (A,B and C) have selected among 8 keys with each having probability 1/8.

If key A has successfully unlocked then there is no need to unlock the house by B and C .

If key A become unsuccessful but by key B if house is Unlocked then there is no need to unlock by key C.

If key A and B have unsuccessful then by key C we can unlocked the house.

P(get into house by three key)= (4/10) + (6/10)*(1/8) + (6/10)*(7/8)*(1/8) + (6/10)*(7/8)*(7/8)*(1/8).

Is my approach correct?

Comment: there is a $.4$ chance that the house is unlocked, and a $\frac 38=.375$ chance that you have the right key.  Thus the answer is $.4\times 1+.6\times .375$.

Comment: Your answer confuses the $.6$ and the $.4$ and the factors of $\frac 78$ are unwanted.

Comment: Each among keys A,B and C have probability to be successfully open house is 1/8 and probability of failure is (7/8).

Comment: Yes, that is true.  But still, the factors of $\frac 78$ are irrelevant.  If $A$ is the correct key then the (conditional) probability that $B,C$ don't work is $1$, not $\frac 78$.

Comment: To see that your method is wrong (aside from jumbling the $.6's$ and the $.4's$) suppose that you brought all $8$ keys.  Then the answer is obviously $1$.  Indeed, $.4\times 1 .6\times \frac 88$=1$.  Your calculation does not yield $1$.

Comment: If we brought all the key then probability to open the house is 8*(1/8) = 1.

Comment: Yes, but your method does not give $1$.

Comment: Probability that Key A and B fails to open the house is (1 - 1/8).  So probability that Key C open the house while A and B fails = (1/8)*(7/8)*(7/8). Where I am wrong.

Comment: These are not independent events.  If $A$ works then we know that $B,C$ do not work.  Thus the probability that $A$ works but $B,C$ don't is just $\frac 18$.

Comment: @lulu , Thanks . I got my answer.  P(get into house by three key)= (4/10) + (6/10)(1/8)(1)(1) + (6/10)(1)(1/8) (1)+ (6/10)(1)(1)(1/8).

Comment: Yes, as I say:  $.4\times 1 +.6\times \frac 38$.

Comment: But your interpretation is different. You are saying that three key become successful with probability 3/8. So, P(get into house by three key)= (4/10) + (6/10)(3/8). Is this your logic? Please let me know your logic.

Comment: It's the same either way.  You get $.4\times 1 +.6\times \left(\frac 18+\frac 18+\frac 18\right)$.

Comment: I agree but interpretation is different?

Comment: I don't see how.

Comment: First way to solve it( 1)three key become successful with probability 3/8. So, P(get into house by three key)= (4/10) + (6/10)(3/8).  Second way is (2) Let the 3 keys (A,B and C) have selected among 8 keys with each having probability 1/8.

If key A has successfully unlocked then there is no need to unlock the house by B and C .

If key A become unsuccessful but by key B if house is Unlocked then there is no need to unlock by key C.

If key A and B have unsuccessful then by key C we can unlocked the house.

Comment: All you are doing is confirming the (evident) fact that if you choose $3$ keys randomly you have a $\frac 38$ chance of getting the right one.

Comment: No, I am testing each key with probability (1/8). And conditional probability of the failure of other two keys is 1 while one successful ,as you mentioned in one of your comments.

Comment: But you needn't go through all that, it doesn't add anything.  It is one of the core axioms of probability that the probability of a union of mutually exclusive events is the sum of the individual probabilities.  That's all you need.